# SQL Query for cumulative Multiplication and Sum

Tags: sql

I am trying to achieve the below manipulated cumulative sum

[image]

Have written the following SQL , however this bit of the query needs correction
 ELSE ( Exp(Sum(Log(Abs(NULLIF( total  , 0))))) +value )
as the +value bit is not being taken in to account for consecutive aggregations.

Thanks for your help!!

```
with DTA AS
(
select *,  case when id = 1  then  value*Multiplier  else  Abs(NULLIF(Multiplier,0))  end as total from testTable
)
,
DTB AS (
SELECT id,value,Multiplier,total,
(SELECT 
       CASE              
                 WHEN B.id = 1 THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,5), B.total)                                              
                 ELSE ( Exp(Sum(Log(Abs(NULLIF( total  , 0))))) +value ) 
               END
        FROM   DTA a 
        WHERE  B.id >= A.id) as  cumulativeSum

FROM   DTA B
)

select * from DTB order by id asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
select tt.*,
       exp(sum(log(nullif(abs(value * multiplier), 0))) over (order by id)) as cumulativeProduct
from testTable tt;
```

Comment: No, that does not address the problem (+value) part is missed and the single query suggested eliminates cumulative sum after row 3 to 0.77 for the above mentioned values

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved it by adding a custom aggregate function via C# and registering the dll in SQL server.

Reference :[Custom Aggregates in SQL Server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170061/Custom-Aggregates-in-SQL-Server)